# Install Kolab 3.3 on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, kolab

I tried following the installation guide for Kolab on CentOS6, but cannot get it to complete. I couldn't get the key as the keyserver was not responding, and even bypassing the keycheck, the install had too many failed dependencies... some which should already seem to be on the server. Has anyone completed an install recently? Kolab 3.3 on CentOS 6.5. I could not find any good information on the issues. http://docs.kolab.org/installation-guide/centos.html

Answer (score 0):

I just did a complete 3.3 installation on CentOS 6.5 as mentioned.

In order to receive the key i had to break the command

```
gpg --search devel@lists.kolab.org
```

and re-run it. The second run delivered the key.